# How can I tell if a QuickTime movie is prepared for streaming?

Tags: video, streaming, quicktime

I have been given a QuickTime file to place on a web site for my client. I requested the file be prepared for streaming using "Fast Start - Compressed Header" so that the video with start to play as soon as QuickTime player has buffered enough. (We will *not* be using a QuickTime Streaming Server for this video)

I am unsure if the file provided to me meets my request. For one, it seems to be am MPEG4 file, not an MPEG4 video file wrapped in a QuickTime `.mov` container. But even when I export a short ~10 second clip using "fast Start - Compressed Header" and open that in QuickTime player, nothing I can see under Movie Properties or Movie Information shows me that I have added a fast start header.

How can I determine if a QuickTime movie file is prepared for streaming using Fast Start, Compressed Header?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [QTIndexSwapper](http://renaun.com/blog/code/qtindexswapper/) by Renaun Erickson. It's an Adobe AIR app that detects if a movie is ready for web and if not it tries to move the index (header) to the beginning of the file thus allowing a simultaneous download and playback.